# ValueError: can only call with other PeriodIndex-ed objects

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes together.  Ironically, they started out as part of the same dataframe, but I am making baby steps -- sometimes in the wrong direction.
Frame 1 looks like this:

```
Int64Index: 10730 entries, 0 to 10729
Data columns (total 6 columns):
RegionID      10730 non-null int64
RegionName    10730 non-null object
State         10730 non-null object
Metro         10259 non-null object
CountyName    10730 non-null object
SizeRank      10730 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2), object(4)
```

Frame 2 looks like this:

```
Int64Index: 10730 entries, 0 to 10729
Data columns (total 82 columns):
1996Q2    8218 non-null float64
1996Q3    8229 non-null float64
1996Q4    8235 non-null float64
.....
2016Q1    10730 non-null float64
2016Q2    10730 non-null float64
2016Q3    10730 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(82)
```

Notice that the indexes are of the same type, and they even have the same number of rows.
I am trying to merge the dataframes back together like so:

```
df4 = pd.merge(df3, df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
ValueError: can only call with other PeriodIndex-ed objects
```

The 2016Q1 and similarly named columns in the 2nd dataframe are of Period type, but I am not merging on them -- I thought as long as the indexes line up, merge should work?  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a reduced sample ([mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) of your data of both frames? I see absolutely no problem with your code (that is if df3 and df2 are indeed Frame 1 and Frame 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have the following DFs:

```
In [44]: df1
Out[44]:
   1996Q2  2000Q3    2010Q4
0     1.5     3.5  1.000000
1    22.0    38.5  2.000000
2    15.0    35.0  4.333333

In [45]: df1.columns
Out[45]: PeriodIndex(['1996Q2', '2000Q3', '2010Q4'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

Notice: `df1.columns` are of the `PeriodIndex` dtype

```
In [46]: df2
Out[46]:
    a   b   c
0  a1  b1  c1
1  a2  b2  c2
2  a3  b3  c3

In [47]: df2.columns
Out[47]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

`merge` and `join` will return: `ValueError: can only call with other PeriodIndex-ed objects` as, AFAIK, Pandas DF can't have a mixed column dtypes if some of them are of `PeriodIndex` dtype:

```
In [48]: df1.join(df2)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: can only call with other PeriodIndex-ed objects
```

`merge` throws the same exception:

```
In [54]: pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: can only call with other PeriodIndex-ed objects
```

So we will have to convert `df1.columns` to strings:

```
In [49]: df1.columns = df1.columns.values.astype(str)

In [50]: df1.columns
Out[50]: Index(['1996Q2', '2000Q3', '2010Q4'], dtype='object')
```

Now `join` and `merge` will work:

```
In [51]: df1.join(df2)
Out[51]:
   1996Q2  2000Q3    2010Q4   a   b   c
0     1.5     3.5  1.000000  a1  b1  c1
1    22.0    38.5  2.000000  a2  b2  c2
2    15.0    35.0  4.333333  a3  b3  c3

In [52]: pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[52]:
   1996Q2  2000Q3    2010Q4   a   b   c
0     1.5     3.5  1.000000  a1  b1  c1
1    22.0    38.5  2.000000  a2  b2  c2
2    15.0    35.0  4.333333  a3  b3  c3
```

columns `dtypes` for merged DF:

```
In [58]: df1.join(df2).columns
Out[58]: Index(['1996Q2', '2000Q3', '2010Q4', 'a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

If you need `df1.columns` as `PeriodIndex` after the merging is done - you can save `df1.columns` before you convert them and set them back after you are done with merging / joining:

```
In [60]: df1.columns
Out[60]: PeriodIndex(['1996Q2', '2000Q3', '2010Q4'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')

In [61]: cols_saved = df1.columns

In [62]: df1.columns = df1.columns.values.astype(str)

In [63]: df1.columns
Out[63]: Index(['1996Q2', '2000Q3', '2010Q4'], dtype='object')

# merging (joining) or doing smth else here ...

In [64]: df1.columns = cols_saved

In [65]: df1.columns
Out[65]: PeriodIndex(['1996Q2', '2000Q3', '2010Q4'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

Comment: I understand what you are doing and where you are going with this, however, the string conversion for me does not work the same way.  When I do this "astype" you have suggested, I am getting Index(['105', '106', '107' ...... ], dftype='object')

Comment: @alernerdev, what is your pandas version? I'm using Pandas 0.19.1

Comment: its 0.18.1 -- you think it makes a difference ?

Comment: @alernerdev, i think it makes sense to update to 0.19.1 if you can - there were lots of new features and bug-fixes...

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same issue and was getting integer columns as well.

Instead of

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.values.astype(str)
```

I used

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.format()
```

Hope this helps