# join 2 dataframe, ValueError: can only call with other PeriodIndex-ed objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas df that I am attempting to combine with a `join`. I also apologize as I dont think my code can be replicated. But if I print `head` and `columns` of both df's it looks like this:

df1 =

```
AM_hrs  high_load_hrs   PM_hrs
Date            
2013-06-19  7.50    8.75    7.25
2013-06-20  8.75    7.50    7.50
2013-06-21  5.00    6.25    12.50
2013-06-22  5.00    3.75    15.00
2013-06-23  5.00    11.25   7.50
```

df2 =

```
    kWH
Date    
2013-06-19  1458.933333
2013-06-20  1568.150000
2013-06-21  1755.900000
2013-06-22  778.200000
2013-06-23  968.450000
```

df1.columns =

```
Index(['AM_hrs', 'high_load_hrs', 'PM_hrs'], dtype='object')
```

df2.columns =

```
Index(['kWH'], dtype='object')
```

And when I attempt a `df3 = df1.join(df2)` this will throw:
`ValueError: can only call with other PeriodIndex-ed objects`

Any help greatly appreciated... Thanks

Comment: Did you tried the solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/q/40499756/12744275

Comment: Yes I tried about everything in that post alread. About the only work around is saving both df's `to_csv` then read again `pd.read_csv('daily_summary.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)` on both df's. Works just fine then...